# Mongoose one query for all sub documents

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, database

T his is my scheme, I want to do a single `query` and obtain `all documents` and all objects's documents.

```
var CureSchema = mongoose.Schema({

            id:         Number,
            therapist:  {type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:'User'},
            supervisor: {type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:'User'},
            parents:    {type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:'User'},
            children:   {type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:'Child'},
            startate :  Date,
            endDate :   Date,
            deleted:    Boolean,
    });

    var Cure = mongoose.model('Cure', CureSchema);
```

if i use the normal query, i'have `objectId` in the output.

> {
>
> ```
>      "id":0,
>
>   "therapist":ObjectId("5253cbd8d4fb240000000007"),
>
>   "supervisor":ObjectId("5253cc9fd4fb24000000000b"),
>
>   "parents":ObjectId("5253cbdfd4fb240000000008"),
>
>   "children":ObjectId("5253cb31d4fb240000000001"),
>   "deleted":false,
>
>   "startate":   ISODate("2013-10-08T09:13:06.771Z"),
>
>  "_id":ObjectId("5253cca2d4fb24000000000c"),
>  "__v":0
> ```
>
> `}`

Comment: Are you looking for http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Technically it's not possible to do it with one query in mongodb, as the documents belong to three different collections. Mongoose will probably have to do five queries (although I think three should be enough but I'm not sure how smart Mongoose is).

However if what you're really asking is how do get the subdocuments using only one mongoose instruction, you should look to [populate()](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-populate).

```
Cure.find()
  .populate('therapist')
  .populate('supervisor')
  .populate('parents')
  .populate('children')
  .exec(resultHandler);
```

Comment: It work !!!! 

But only for children, why in your opinion ??
It's **Null** for the other

Comment: OK ok .... it's **Null**  if in the db,  the **objectId**, don't have  data or the **objectId** is not correct

Answer (score 0):

You can also use aggregate with a $lookup

```
Cure.aggregate([
   {
       "$lookup": {
          "from": "users",
         "localField": "therapist",
         "foreignField": "_id",
          "as": "therapist"
       }
   },
   {
       "$lookup": {
          "from": "users",
         "localField": "supervisor",
         "foreignField": "_id",
          "as": "supervisor"
       }
   }, ...
  ])
```